# Запятая перед И: "На окнах стоят сетки(,) и насекомые не попадают в дом"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед И?

> На окнах стоят сетки, и насекомые не попадают в дом.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, запятая нужна, так как это солжносочиненное предложение. Если бы не было союза "и", тогда надо было поставить тире.
Уважаемый Серж, на окнах стоят сетки, а не на окнах насекомые не попадают в дом. "На окнах" относится только к первой части предложения, а не ко второй.

Answer (score -3):

Запятая НЕ СТАВИТСЯ, если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общий второстепенный член(чаще всего это обстоятельство места или времени, реже дополнение) или общую придаточную часть:  ***В ветер*** леса шумят великим океанским гулом и вершины сосен гнутся вслед пролетающим облакам.***Сквозь дождь*** лучилось солнце и раскидывалась радуга от края до края . ***На елке в школе*** (вот это общий второстепенный член) дети читали стихи и Дед Мороз вручал им подарки. В вашем случае общий второстепенный член "на окнах"(об-ство места), поэтому запятая не ставится.Подробнее об этом можете почитать в полном академическом справочнике под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Но в нашем предложении "На окнах стоят сетки, и насекомые не попадают в дом" нет никакого общего члена. Или Вы предлагаете "на окнах"?))